# How do I create marginless button bar in Android

Tags: android, layout

I want my application to have button bar at the bottom, that is similar to this one (Motorola Defy+):

[image: bottom button bar]

How can this be achieved? I've tried ButtonBar style with regular buttons in it, but they always have margin in this case.

Comment: See the bottom buttons do not have margin. Not padding.

Comment: Could you show us a image with margins?

Comment: Here I see zero marging and padding for the bar and zero marging and non-zero padding for buttons

Comment: @Evgenyt. Please, don't forget to mark answers. It is not very polite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By code:

Make the bar LinearLayout horizontal. Let´s say its name in code will be bbll.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = bbll.LayoutParams();
params.leftMargin=0;
params.rightMargin=0;
... or params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
bbll.setLayoutParams(params);
```

By layout simply set each margin to 0. That's all. If you have done it and it won't work, put the code here, please.

But you should set `bbll.setPadding(0,0,0,0)` , too. Or you'll see empty space between the bar (that is invisible) and the buttons. aqs has a good thought.